# Separable depthwise convolutions without mixing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to do depthwise separable convolutions, that is, the same filter acts on one channel at a time, without mixing the result, so that necessarily the number of input channels equals the number of output channels. Is that possible at all in Keras/Tensorflow?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/separable_conv2d

Comment: @DavidParks No, that mixes channels at the output.

Comment: Also, that uses different filters for each channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a depthwise separable convolution by definition mixes the channels; you want something a bit different.  That said, here's how you would go about applying the same convolution to different channels, without any mixing between them.

If you know the channel size beforehand, you can use tf.split to split along the channel dimension, apply the same convolution to each channel, then concatenate the results together.  Below are two methods, one which uses a NAMED tf.layers.conv2d and a variable scope to force kernel reuse for each channel, and another which uses tf.nn.conv2d and a declared kernel to achieve the same result (by simply passing the same filter in each time).

You can extend this to multiple filters/channel by changing the 'filters' parameter or the last dimension of the 'kernel' variable, respectively.  However, you would need to follow up with a 1x1 convolution (same setup as the 3x3 convolution, placed inside the for loop) if you wanted to reduce the output back to 1 output channel per 1 input channel.  Activation functions can be applied either inside or outside the for loop without any difference in the output.

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rescale(arr):
    #Quick method to fit output into plotting range
    arr=arr-np.min(arr,(0,1))
    return arr/np.max(arr,(0,1))

def main():
    channels=3
    feed=np.asarray(np.round(np.random.random((1,10,10,channels)),1),np.float32)
    #Feed of shape [batch,height,width,channels]

    individual_channels=tf.split(feed,channels,-1)
    print(individual_channels)

    #With variable scope and tf.layers.conv2d
    results=[]
    with tf.variable_scope('channel_conv',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        for channel in individual_channels:
            #Change conv parameters, add bias, add activation, etc. as desired
            #NAME IS REQUIRED, OTHERWISE A DEFAULT WILL BE ASSIGNED WHICH DIFFERS BY CHANNEL
            #THIS NAME *MUST NOT VARY* THROUGHOUT THE LOOP OR NEW FILTERS WILL BE CREATED
            conv=tf.layers.conv2d(channel,filters=1,kernel_size=[3,3],padding='VALID',use_bias=False,name='conv')
            results.append(conv)

    output=tf.concat(results,-1)

    #With tf.nn.conv2d
    #kernel=tf.get_variable('var', (3,3,1,1),tf.float32)
    #Grabbing previous kernel to show equivalent results, commented out line is how you would create kernel otherwise
    kernel=tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('channel_conv/conv2d/kernel:0')

    results=[]

    for channel in individual_channels:
        #Change conv parameters, add bias, add activation, etc. as desired
        conv=tf.nn.conv2d(channel,kernel,[1,1,1,1],'VALID')
        results.append(conv)

    output2=tf.concat(results,-1)

    #Demonstrate the same output from both methods
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        out,out2=sess.run((output[0],output2[0]))

        fig,axs=plt.subplots(2,1,True,True)
        axs[0].imshow(rescale(out))
        axs[1].imshow(rescale(out2))
        plt.show(fig)
```

Comment: For my tensorflow version, atleast, the kernel name needed to be "channel_conv/conv/kernel:0"

Comment: Furthermore, I found at last a contrib function which does what I asked (and what you did manually): https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/conv2d_in_plane

Comment: Oh, for the name of the kernel I had meant if you just used the tf.nn.conv2d method on its own.  Also, there's been a contrib method since 1.2?  Surprised it hasn't been rolled into tf.layers or tf.nn, it's situationally quite useful.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d` as [shown here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/depthwise_conv2d) should be the solution.

Comment: This does not do what is asked in the original post. To quote the documentation you linked: "depthwise_conv2d applies a different filter to each input channel".